# Convert List<string> into List<string[]> with certain array size

Tags: c#, arrays, excel

I need to convert a plain `List<string>` into a `List<string[]>` with an array size of my choice. I am using ClosedXML library for exporting my objects into Excel and noticed that the library has a built in functionality for populating ranges of cells as following:

```
    // From a list of arrays
    var listOfArr = new List<Int32[]>();
    listOfArr.Add(new Int32[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    listOfArr.Add(new Int32[] { 1 });
    listOfArr.Add(new Int32[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
    var rangeWithArrays = ws.Cell(2, 3).InsertData(listOfArr);
```

[Source](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Showcase&referringTitle=Documentation)

As such the three arrays of integers will get added as rows so I can directly add my list of arrays in one shot.

EDIT:

Seems like no one is understanding the question. I'll provide an example.

Lets say I get an input of `List<string> { "a", "b" , "c", "d" }`. Now how can I convert it into `List<string[]>` where `string[0] {"a", "b" }` and `string[1] {"c", "d" }` and so on. In other terms create string arrays of size 2.

Once again, this is because ClosedXML allows auto populating form of List and that is why I mention it.

Comment: I don't get it, your code seems correct, what is the problem?

Comment: a. Excel and ClosedXML see irrelevant to the question - no point in mentioning them or using them in tags. b. You don't describe what your List<string> is and how you intend it to be converted to a List<string[]> e.g. I have a list of strings, each with comma seperated values and I split each string in a list into an array of strings, splitting on commas and add each array into a new list.

Comment: What example is Int32[] not string and variable lengths.   What have you tried?

Comment: The code is a hardcoded sample. I need to be able to convert any input of type List<string> into form depicted by the three independent string arrays which is List<string[]>.

Comment: Why don't you use object array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it a `List<string>` to `string[]`?

```
string[] ArrayOfStrings = MyList.ToArray()
```

If you want parts with sizes, you can do it:

```
 int size = 5;
 List<string[]> ArrList = new List<string[]>();
 for (var i = 0; i < myList.Count; i+=size)
 { 
     ArrList.Add(myList.Skip(i).Take(size).ToArray());   
 }
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: I need to be able to specify array sizes with the list of arrays

Answer (score 1):

Daniel is right. But I understood that you wanted a List of string arrays. In that case you can try something like this. I wrote that in Notepad so check for errors.

```
List<string[]> ConvertToListOfArrays(List<string> list, int arraySize)
{
    List<string[]> listOfArrays = new List<string[]>();
    foreach(string item in list)
    {
        string[] newArray = new string[arraySize];
        newArray[0] = item;
        listOfArrays.Add(newArray);
    }
    return listOfArrays;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] sampleList = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
int splitFactor = 2;
List<string[]> splitedList = new List<string[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < sampleList.Length; i += splitFactor)
{
    //Skip(i) means ignore (i) elements from start of sampleList
    // and start from (i+1)th element.
    //And Take(splitFactor) means give me an array of string to the size of (splitFactor)
    //And finally .ToArray() convert the IEnumerable<string> to string[]
    //Then we simply add it to splittedList
    splitedList.Add(sampleList.Skip(i).Take(splitFactor).ToArray());
}
```

So what happens here is when **"i"=0**, the Linq query starts from it's **first element** and **take the 2 elements (0 and 1)**, then in increment part of "for" "i" is going to +=2, so **"i" is 2 now** and the Linq query **skip 2 elements at the beginning** (skip 0 and 1) and starts to **get the 2 elements from 2th index** of array (3 and 4) and it continuous till "i" reaches the sampleList.Length (4)

I hope I explained enough, If you still need more explanation tell me.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.